# `map(&:to_i)` doesn't work on tryruby.org?

Tags: ruby

I am trying to convert an array of strings that are numbers to integers. This does not work on tryruby.org:

```
arr1
# => "123"
arr1.split­(//).map(&:to_i)­
# => #<TypeError: wrong argument type NilClass (expected Proc)>
```

Any idea on what the issue is?

Comment: Inspect the results of `arr1.split(//)`

Comment: Does it work in your local ruby environment?

Comment: `arr1.split(//) #=> ['1', '2', '3']`

Comment: yeah, must be that tryruby doesn't run real complete ruby. Or something like this.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I am currently learning ruby on the internet. Now I am trying to solve the problems on Coderbyte.com and I am using tryruby.org to check each part cause in the former you only get the return value of what you made. Can you suggest me where to check bits of code? maybe another more advanced online ruby environment? or go ahead and make a local ruby environment? and which version to use, latest ruby version? (edit: what version is Coderbyte.com maybe you know?)

Comment: Go ahead and install Ruby on your machine. I advice using simply newest Ruby version (you can use rvm or rbenv to manage Ruby versions).

Comment: @MarekLipka thank you, will do that!

Comment: for anyone other in my situation I used rubyinstaller.org, downloaded the recommended 2.1.x download (dont get the 64bit), in installation I checked everything, then went to command prompt and type irb which will make the command prompt work like tryruby.org. (I commented this cause it took some searching around to figure out what to do)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there's some bug on `tryruby.org`, because it works locally for me on `ruby-1.9.3-p392` (try-ruby.org  ruby version):

```
>> arr1 = '123'
=> "123"
>> arr1.split(//).map(&:to_i)
=> [1, 2, 3]
>> RUBY_VERSION
=> "1.9.3"
>> RUBY_PATCHLEVEL
=> 392
```